# overflow-y: scroll or auto not working as intended. It is not scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, less

I am using vue.js with less. I am trying to scroll a div with overflow but its is not working it stays like overflow:hidden

[Screenshot of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C48dz.png)

This is the code

```
<template>
  <div class="chatarea" v-if="currentRoom">
    <ChatInput />
    <div class="chatbox">
      <ChatBit
        :message="chats.message"
        :sender="chats.username"
        v-for="(chats, index) in messages[currentRoom]"
        :key="index"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

This is the css

```
<style lang="less" scoped>
.chatarea {
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #3b3d47 - #222222;
  .chatbox {
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    // height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
}
</style>
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Try giving fixed height to your chatarea class. Like `height: 100vh` or something.

Comment: `height: 100%;` of the parents height wont work if the parent has no fixed height. The browser doesnt know what to apply 100% then too. Also you only get a scrollbar if an element actually overflows. If the element has no height smaller then the content, no overflow will appear and as such no scrollbar have any influence.

Comment: @tacoshy Thanks but I can't understand it clearly. What should I do then?

Comment: I recommend you to add a code-snippet instead of a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

in this case you have commented the line that you set a height to the element that you want it to scroll, just replace this block of code :
`height: 600px; // You had commented this line`

and it's better to set `overflow` to `auto`, therfore if the chat does't scroll (height of chats is less that height of container) the scroll bar not show and it does't make your UI bad.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone who helped. The problem was in `justify-content:flex-end` I removed the line and everything started to work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I use the css `overflow-y` attribute, I would normaly use the value `auto` instead of `scroll`.

Here is your css that I changed, and now it should work for you. VueJS isn't the problem here.

```
<style lang="less" scoped>
.chatarea {
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #3b3d47 - #222222;
  .chatbox {
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    // height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work `auto` just hides the scrollbar forever..

Comment: @AnupamKrishna you don't need the scrollbar to scroll up and down.

Comment: It doesn't scroll up or down. It behaves like overflow: hidden

Comment: hm. that's strange. on my macbook, when I scroll up and down it works when I scroll up and down.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving max-height attribute

```
.chatarea {
  width: calc(100% - 300px); 
  height: 100%; // suggest you to 100vh
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #3b3d47 - #222222;
  .chatbox {
    max-height: calc(100% - 50px);
    // height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
}
```